# Macro to return a unique string at compile-time

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, objective-c-runtime

Is there a Macro that can return a unique-string at compile-time, so that it could be used as the name of an objective-c class?

I'm thinking of something like:

```
#define my_macro(params) \
@implementation my_macro_function_giving_unique_string_(MyTrickyRuntimeExtension) \
  //Do stuff \
@end \
```

Comment: If the macro generated a "magical" name, how would you know what it generated so you can refer to it elsewhere? Most things that you define need to be referenced in order to be used.

Comment: Explain what you are *actually* trying to achieve.

Comment: @unwind I don't want to refer to it, i want to fire the +Initialize method that is required by the Obj-C runtime to run once on start-up. From there the initialize method will do some magic.

Comment: @JasperBlues I'm still not sure exactly what you want. Why do you need a unique identifier for that?

Comment: You have tagged this question with at least three separate languages (C, C++, Objective-C). In what language do you need the resulting code to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a macro `__COUNTER__` predefined in Visual Studio that could help

I used *iammilind* suggestions

```
#define UNIQUE2(param) YourClassBaseNames##param
#define UNIQUE1(param) UNIQUE2(param)
#define UNIQUE UNIQUE1(__COUNTER__)

class UNIQUE
{

};

class UNIQUE
{

};
```

counter - returns new count ech time

reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay(v=vs.80).aspx

it is also available in GCC

Comment: `##` doesn't work that way. You have to do it through other macros, or use Boost.PP: `BOOST_PP_CAT(base, __COUNTER__)`.

Comment: @fen Thanks. . . is it available on clang, do you know?

Comment: @fen - ooooh. That could work actually. nice. . . i'll wait for 30 more mins before accepting.

Comment: Isn't `__COUNTER__` an extension ? I remember that it's not the part of c++03 standard at least.

Comment: Seems like its not working on standard Apple gear with clang.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, it can be:

```
#define UNIQUE_NAME2(LINE) Class##LINE
#define UNIQUE_NAME1(LINE) UNIQUE_NAME2(LINE)
#define UNIQUE_NAME UNIQUE_NAME1(__LINE__)
```

And just use it as:

```
class UNIQUE_NAME {};
```

[Note: Declare 1 class per line and don't hope for forward declaring it anywhere :)]

Comment: I thought about it. 1) You can't add neighter c-tor nor d-tor. 2) You can't create a variable of this class unless `class UNIQUE_NAME {} var;`. Maybe use `__COUNTER__` ...

Comment: @iammilind Thanks! Can you explain how it works, a little. . I'm not very good at C++.

Comment: @iammilind Maybe add `__FILE__` macro to avoid similar class names, defined in different files but at equal lines

Comment: @iammilind I don't think the ____FILE____ macro will work for a class name, will it?

Comment: @borisbn, No __FILE__ doesn't work as it will contain `/` or `\` for fully qualified name. The OP hasn't mentioned requirement of constructor or destructor. If that's needed then this will not work.

Comment: yes... it's my fault. Everybody - do not look at my prev. comment ))